# WPF Treeview. No updating

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a tree view with bind to some ObservableCollection, which is filled with some asyncronous function. The problem is that it's not getting updated on UI after the asyncronous command worked and updated the source collection (added some child nodes or something like that). My XAML looks like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Node.Caption, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <TreeView  Style="{DynamicResource FormItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" >
    </TreeView>

</StackPanel>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you update the collection? What type of elements do you add?

Comment: I've just debugged it with Threads window. The collection is updated in the separated thread by my asynchronous command, and then the UI updated in the main Thread (the RaisePropertyChanged is involved), but no changes on UI... I have a class FilingPathTreeNode, which contains the ObservableCollection of the FilingPathTreeNode objects. With the debug i get, that the collection is updated correctly. But i can see no changes on UI. The same, but synchronous command gives me the expected result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you, guys. It was a silly mistake of mine. I just didn't set DataContexts of one control and of the window using this control. So it turned out that they had different contexts, because my ViewModel isn't a singleton. I should have been more careful about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're updating your UI on the correct thread?

Comment: So you bind your data on the UI thread for sure? Just want to confirm that you're setting whatever the data context is using the Dispatcher?